# How to change Saints Row 4 aspect ratio from portrait to landscape?

Tags: pc, linux, saints-row-iv

I just started Saints Row IV for the first time, and it's wrongly chosen an aspect ratio of 10:16. That sometimes happens because I've got one vertical and one horizontal screen. In most games I just change it in the options, however:

- It looks like the main menu has been scaled for a screen size of 3072x1920 (16:10) and then *cropped* to the right-most 1200x1920, so **most of it is unreadable**: [image: Main menu as displayed]
- When I managed to get to the display menu (third from the bottom on the main menu, then second from the bottom), it says something at the bottom that looks like **"Aspect ratio can only be toggled in the title screen"**. Once I get to the title screen, how do I do that? I tried setting the resolution in `~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Saints Row IV/display.ini`, but the game seems to ignore those changes.

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with the game settings several times it eventually stuck. Here's the configuration diff if anyone else might be helped by it:

```
$ diff ~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Saints\ Row\ IV/display.ini{.orig,}
5,9c5,9
< ResolutionWidth = 1200
< ResolutionHeight = 1920
< RefreshRate = 59
< MSAA_Level = 2
< Fullscreen = true
---
> ResolutionWidth = 1920
> ResolutionHeight = 1200
> RefreshRate = 60
> MSAA_Level = 1
> Fullscreen = false
24c24
< VSync = false
---
> VSync = true
28c28
< Preset = 2
---
> Preset = 4
34c34
< AnisoLevel = 2
---
> AnisoLevel = 16
37c37
< LightingDetail = 1
---
> LightingDetail = 2
40c40
< SSAO_Level = 1
---
> SSAO_Level = 3
45c45
< ShadowDetail = 1024
---
> ShadowDetail = 4096
49c49
< SceneDetail = 2
---
> SceneDetail = 3
52c52
< Reflections = 1
---
> Reflections = 2
62c62
< PostProcess = 1
---
> PostProcess = 2
```